# How do I create and use TJAlarmManager with Delphi XE5?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

I do not understand this really.

example:

```
alarm: TJAlarmManager;
test: JAlarmManager;

test:= alarm.Create;
alarm.Init(test, z <-???);
```

What does the pointer in this constructor mean ?
`alarm:=TJAlarmManager.create(o:alarmmanger,p:pointer)`

As I understand it, one must also generate a `JPendingIntentClass`.

Can someone give a a small code sample how to use this class?

Comment: The pointer links to a procedure that receives the alarm notification.

Comment: The AlarmManager is a wrapper class around Android's: see here for the android doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html  (Although that doesn't look that enlightening vis-a-vis your question)

Comment: To edit many thanks my post, unfortunately, my English is not so good

Comment: Never mind your English, very few people are native speakers. My Zulu is terrible.  Oh and never again apologize for bad English there are 4000 living languages and only 60* million native English speakers.

Comment: This does not look like valid Delphi code to me: `Create(o:alarmmanager ...)`, this syntax looks like Java.